# Why is Norway spruce dead at top

Tags: diagnosis

Just recently had it sprayed from professional as suggested for boost and growth. Could it be from that or something else.  They are coming back next week.

[image]

Comment: when did the top die back?  This does not usually happen overnight...was it dead before?  What did they spray and what for?

Comment: Any branch that lost its needles is not coming back. If the problem is corrected ,it is likely to develop a  new leader from the live wood .

Comment: Spraying a conifer for "boost and growth" - is that "boost and growth of the professional's bank balance?" Conifers don't need foliar feeding like tomatoes!!!

Comment: I think the professional's tummy also had boost and growth. If I were you, I would tell everybody I know how bad this “professional” is. Write to your local newspaper. BTW, who is coming back next week? Professionals or spruces?

Comment: We noticed this in Spring. I can’t recall if it was before he sprayed or after. I’m not sure if it is a white pine weevle. I see some white sap coming down the tree. Sadly I guess our only choice is to cut top off then put a new leader up. Not happy with tree guy though. He’s coming today and I am going to let him know.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to give a useful answer when you provide scarce data (as also noted in comments).

My best impression based on what we have is that the root system simply for some reason does not have enough energy to support the whole plant. But it may recover (meaning, root system). Bare branches can be cut off, or even should be cut off. And water generously this and the next year. No fertilizer ever. No spraying ever. Just water. The plant will find its new leader by itself, do not bother helping it. Once you notice significant recovery, decrease watering to reasonable levels, and, again, no fertilizers of any kind. I wish you success!